# Why does $(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^n =(\cos n\theta + i \sin n \theta)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it the Euler identity $$ e^{i \theta} =(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$$
$$ e^{i n \theta} =(\cos n \theta + i \sin n \theta)$$

Comment: You can find multiple derivations at the wikipedia page for [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Comment: Right, that's what I was getting at with Euler. But does Euler have to be derived from DeMoivre or vice versa? Or do both ways work?

Comment: The linked page shows that you can prove the above either by using Euler's identity or induction. As for your question about using the above to prove Euler's identity, in short, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints (sketches)

**First Proof: Trigonometric identities + induction:** $\;\;\;\;$   For $\,n=2\;$ :

$$(\cos +i\sin t)^2=\cos^2t-\sin^2t+2i\cos t\sin t=\cos 2t+i\sin 2t$$

Induction:

$$(\cos t+i\sin t)^{n+1}=(\cos +i\sin t)^n(\cos +i\sin t)\stackrel{\text{ind. Hyp.}}=(\cos nt+i\sin nt)(\cos +i\sin t)=$$

$$=\cos nt\cos t-\sin nt\sin t+i(\sin nt\cos t+\sin t\cos nt)=\ldots\ldots$$

**Second "Proof": Using polar representation**

$$(\cos t+i\sin t)^n=\left(e^{it}\right)^n=e^{int}=\ldots\ldots$$

You can see that the second proof is way easier and direct than the first one...yet it requires to know some stuff that makes it so.

Choose yours...:)

Comment: You mean the second proof requires the knowledge of the proof of the Euler identity (the Taylor expansion)?

Comment: That, or else that $\,(a^m)^n=a^{mn}\,$ for complex base $\,a\,$ or, at least, for **this** complex base...It's basic, yet it is taught *usually* at a later stage, so that the proof of de Moivre's formula is *usually* done the first, pretty basic, way.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove geometrically, that if you take a right-angle triangle a:b:x, and a second triangle c:d:y, that the 'product' of these produces a ray $xy$ at the sum of the angles.

The proof runs like this.

```
                BD"                            Lengths are shown as 'inches' (")
             Qo---oR          OP = XC"         Angles are shown as 'degrees' (°)
                  | AD"       PQ = XD"         Points names have no extra symbol
                  |           OQ = XY"
                 Po                            OPQ is in the ratio cx:dx:yx
                  | BC"       POA = m°                ie  c:d:y.
       Oo---AC"---oA          POQ = n°  AOQ = (m+n)°
```

Triangle OAP and PRQ are similar triangles in the ratio of a:b:x, scaled by c and d.

Triangle OPQ is a triangle in the ratio c:d:y, scaled by the measure x.

The line APR is straight, we can then use cartesian coordinates to define O at (0,0) etc.  Writing the right-angle coordinate as $a+bi$, it is possible to show that $i^2=-1$, when the nature of 'multiply' is taken to be add the angles, and multiply the rays.

The coordinate of OQ is $(AC-BD)+i(BC+AD)$.  When this is written as the product $(A+iB)(C+iD)$, it gives directly that $i^2=-1$.

From this, we have then that $cis(x) = \cos(x)+i \sin(x)$ has a length of one, and an angle of $x$.  The n'þ power of this has a radius of 1, and an angle of nx, ie

$$(\cos(x)+j \sin(x))^n = \cos(nx)+\sin(nx)$$

follows directly.

Comment: I don't understand the way you tried to prove (and thus you may want to ponder to add a diagram or a link to a diagram to make your ideas clearer), but anyway: please note that in mathematics the imaginary unit is usually denoted by $\,i\,$ and not by $\,j\,$ , as many times physicists do.

Comment: It's a simple proof that complex multiplication equates to rotation and scaling.

Comment: Perhaps, yet I can't see it the way it is shown here. Maybe it's only me, though...

Comment: I have this as a png file on my machine, with all the lines in it, but ascii art is my limit here, and the missing lines form the triangle OPQ.  In short, writing $cis(x) = e^{ix}$ is not a proof, since it wades into deeper water.

Comment: $\,cis(x)=e^{ix}\,$ certainly is not a proof but simply a definition.

Comment: It was presented as the 'second proof' in the accepted answer.  Also, it is not a definition, since $cis(x)$ is $\cos(x)+i \sin(x)$, which is a separate thing to $e^{ix}$.  You have to do something to demonstrate that $e^{2\pi} = 1$.  The proof i gave above shows that angles correspond to an exponent, but it does not prove the base of the exponent.

Comment: No, the notational *definition* $\;cis x=e^{ix}\,$ was *not* presented as second proof. Read again and hopefully you'll get convinced of this. Of course, one can set up things as to have that *as a theorem* and use *other* definitions to arrive there. Anyway, the second proof in my answer relates, as explained there, to exponent laws with complex numbers, which do not apply in general but in this case the mentioned rule with the mentioned complex number applies. About the proof you say you presented I can't tell much as I don't understand it.

Comment: $cis(x)$ is an abbreviation for $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$.  This is an algebraic expression in a $\cos$, $\sin$, and $i$.  You can use any angle measure for $x$, typically, degrees might be used.  The second 'proof', simply asserts that you can suppose that $cis(x)$ is identical to $exp(ix)$, as opposed, to say $2x$ or $2^x$.  It's true, but the relation is proveable, not a definition.

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't know: it starts with $\cos(x)+i \sin(x) = e^{ix}$, seems pretty much like starting off with what you want to prove.

Comment: No @Wendy.krieger, what we all want to prove is $\;(cis\, x)^n=cis(nx)\;$, using your notation.